# Can open tables with sa user name from SSMS but cant log in to the software using sa user name

Tags: sql-server

I copied one DB from one computer and restore it successfully to an other one.

I can open the tables and see all transactions on the new computer using `sa` user name, but cannot log in to the ERP software using that account.

I noticed that when I run this query:

```
SELECT d.name, d.is_master_key_encrypted_by_server
  FROM sys.databases AS d
```

Number 1 is next to the DB that I am trying to log in.

Any solutions or ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of SQL Server you’re using, you may want to double check the security settings of the new server to ensure it’s in “Mixed Mode”:

1. Login to SQL Server Management Studio
2. In the SSMS Object Explorer, right-click the new server, and click “Properties”
3. Under the Server Properties, select the “Security” tab
4. Confirm the Server authentication is set to “SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode” and click OK
5. Restart the server and confirm that you can connect as `sa`

**Note:** It’s generally bad practice to give an application complete control over the database server. If at all possible, have your ERP use an account created specifically for it, ensuring the permissions are adequately limited.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I did all the above, I created new user and give dbo role and all permissions; I can open the tables from SQL management Studio and see the transactions using this new user, but still can NOT log in into the ERP software with this user.  It giving me User Authentication Failed...

Answer (score 0):

> cannot log in to the ERP software using that account.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to log into a separate software (*which may connected to the database you refer here*) with an user account created for SQL server.

If this is the case, this doesn't work. You need to have a separate account which is specific to the software you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in the old laptop, I can access the ERP software using sa user name and password; but when I restored the same DB to a new laptop, i cant log in to the ERP software using sa user name and password, even though, sa password is the same for both Laptops.

Comment: May be you had setup the same credentials for the ERP software.